# Docxtemplater all tags are rendered as undefined

Tags: node.js, undefined

Im using [docxtemplater](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater) in my Node.js application to fill out the tags in my .docx file. I have to retrieve data from mongoose which i than transform to an JavaScript object via `.toObject()`. Than i loop trough all the data until i have everything i need and try to add it to the .docx file like this: `doc.setData(JSON.stringify(textToAdd));`. Also without `JSON.stringitfy` i wan't work. All tags get rendered as `undefined`

My console shows me the data like this `{"testtag":"testtext"}`, which should work. Because when i copy it from the console and test it like this `doc.setData({"testtag":"testtext"});` it works. Am im missing something?

Comment: try `doc.setData(textToAdd);` without using `JSON.stringify()`, I'm assuming that `textToAdd` is the object with data.

Comment: That's what i tried first.  `JSON.stringify()` was what i tried after.

Comment: So it turns out that it was the `JSON.stringify()` .. Thanks

Comment: For whom it may concern, I thought I had this problem too but my script was outputting to another folder and I was looking at an old output - so it was working but just not outputting where I thought it was.